# Create a Pandas DataFrame using the print() function

Tags: function, printing

we will require you to create a Pandas DataFrame in four different ways. There's no need to worry about assigning index values at this stage. Remember to use the print() function to display the desired output.

Use pandas to create the following DataFrame, and call it df:
To complete the task, create a dictionary called data where the values should be lists.

[pandas DataFrames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBiUs.png)